# Help with Python/Qt4 and QTableWidget column click

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I'm trying to learn PyQt4 and GUI design with QtDesigner.  I've got my basic GUI designed, and I now want to capture when the user clicks on a column header.

My thought is that I need to override QTableWidget, but I don't know how to attach to the signal.  Here's my class so far:

```
class MyTableWidget(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL('itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*)'), self.onClick)

    def onClick(self):
        print "Here!"
```

But, setting a breakpoint in the onClick, nothing is firing.

Can somebody please help me?

TIA
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the SIGNAL needed is:

```
self.connect(self.horizontalHeader(), SIGNAL('sectionClicked(int)'), self.onClick)
```

Comment: Does that solve the problem??? Don't you need to make onClick take self and the int passed by sectionClicked???

Comment: mandel, yes, it appears to.  And yes, I did need the int in onClick as well.  I was trying to get the signaling working first before implementation.